# What is the best/fastest way to toggle between the Main site and Meta site?

Tags: support, meta

When I'm on either site, I have trouble finding a link to the other.  If we're trying to drive participation in both aspects of this Beta, it would be great to be able to browse between them smoothly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to navigate between the main and meta sites is to use the links in your topbar navigation.

When you're on the main site, you see a link that says "meta":
[image: main]

When on meta, that link changes to "main":
[image]

These navigation options will allow you to switch between the main site and meta site regardless of what page you're currently on (a particular question page, the homepage, a user profile, etc.). There are other links, like the links to active or featured meta questions that appear in the Community Bulletin in the right sidebar, but the top nav links are the easiest because they are always there.

Comment: For the record, I'd been using SO for quite a while before I worked that out... I always used to change the URL to get back to the main site!!

Comment: Cool!  I'd never noticed those links before.